# Linking my Bitcoin address to my EOS account name

Tags: account-name, bitcoin, private-key

Is there some type of eos data field where I can store my Bitcoin address and other crypto addresses inside the eos blockchain? I should be able to query this data easily too.

I want to create a service where one can store their btc address and a signed message using the btc private key of the EOS account name. This proves that the EOS account name owns that bitcoin address.

Now I can just give out my eos account name without having to remember or lookup my bitcoin address and people can now send me BTC.

How can i do this?

Comment: You might want to look at the memo fields that most transactions use to store information

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own contract which can store string (representing your address) in `eosio::multi_index` table. Table can be accessed easily by RPC call, because the changes are stored in state. (not need to replay all actions to achieve current state)

Comment: any cost associated? ram? let's say i have 10000 records

Comment: It costs RAM. Each row will consume the size of data and indices. In your case, bitcoin address usually have 26-35 length string (26-35 bytes) and you need 64-bit unsigned integer ID for primary key. Primary index will consume 112 bytes and if you add secondary index of 256-bit integer by hashing address by sha256 to search for it easily, it will consume 160 bytes more.

Comment: whats the average cost of this?